# What sustains residential real estate prices in California when household incomes are low?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, income, california, housing

I have a question which assumes the accuracy of two links ([here](http://www.justice.gov/ust/eo/bapcpa/20130401/bci_data/median_income_table.htm), for median income, and [here](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2013-05-15/california-median-home-price-passed-400-000-last-month.html), for median home price, both of which are in California).  I'm going to make an erroneous assumption and state that the median income in California is actually what the 4 person household makes (see the link and table); meaning about $76,000.  I'm admitting that this isn't the actual true median though (more than likely, based averages, it would be closer to $63,000 to $65,000).

Considering that the median home price in California is $400,000 and the median income is $76,000, what sustains this housing market in California (*if* it's sustainable)?  Asked differently, why shouldn't anyone be shorting the California housing market, as, unless incomes increase, this appears unsustainable (home prices are at least `5x` the price of incomes and from the articles I've read, they're growing in cost; good mortgage advisors generally suggest a person only buy a house `3x` their income - `4x` their income is generally seen as questionable)?

Forgot to mention, this question is partially based on [these criteria for buying a home](http://files.consumerfinance.gov/f/201312_cfpb_mortgagerules.pdf).

Comment: Maybe because currently interest rates are low, so more people are buying and that sustains the demand? just a thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A well-written mortgage would allow ratios of 28/36, i.e. 28% of gross income going to cover housing. $400K times 80% LTV requies a $320K mortgage, at 4.5%, a $1621 payment. If we multiply this by 4, then the 12 months' income is $78K or so. (I just set payment to be 25% of income.)

In my riveting article [You want to lend that couple how much?](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/you-want-to-lend-that-couple-how-much/) I discuss how some mortgage brokers will go far higher than these ratios.

Note, also, your median numbers may be right, but the distribution of incomes does not reflect a bell curve. Last, note that the 3X, 4X, etc numbers are not static. They change based on interest rates. You can afford far more at 4% than at 9%.

Answer (score 5):

The story about median home prices states:

> "single-family detached home climbed to $402,760 last month,"

That means it doesn't include townhouses, condos, apartments. Many of which are cheaper.

The apparent disparity also doesn't address the case when young people share a place as roommates.